# dispaly list of cards in react

Tags: reactjs, react-props, bootstrap-cards

new with react
i want to know why my cards are not showing up in the body when i pass them some minimal data.

so this is my code:

```
import CardsList from "./cardsList";

function allCards() {
  const cardsArr = [
    {
      id: 1,
      image:
        "https://images.pexels.com/photos/784849/pexels-photo-784849.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2",
      country: "usa",
      fullName: "rafa rafa",
      cost: "25$",
      duration: "day",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      image:
        "https://images.pexels.com/photos/784849/pexels-photo-784849.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2",
      country: "poland",
      fullName: "rafa rafa",
      cost: "45$",
      duration: " 2 days",
    },
  ];

  return <CardsList cards={cardsArr} />;
}

export default allCards;
```

```
import OneCard from "../common/card/card";

function cardsList(props) {
  if (props.cards.length === 0) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>No users found</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="cardsList">
      <ul>
        {props.cards.map((card) => {
          <OneCard
            key={card.id}
            id={card.id}
            image={card.image}
            country={card.country}
            fullName={card.fullName}
            cost={card.cost}
            duration={card.duration}
          />;
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default cardsList;
```

```
import ListGroup from "react-bootstrap/ListGroup";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import "./card.css";

function oneCard(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <Card style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
        <Card.Img src={props.image} />
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>{props.CardTitle}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text>{props.CardText}</Card.Text>
        </Card.Body>
        <ListGroup className="list-group-flush">
          <ListGroup.Item>country:{props.country}</ListGroup.Item>
          <ListGroup.Item>full name:{props.fullName}</ListGroup.Item>
          <ListGroup.Item>cost:{props.cost}</ListGroup.Item>
          <ListGroup.Item>duration:{props.duration}</ListGroup.Item>
        </ListGroup>
        <Card.Body id="bodyParentCardLink">
          <Link className="card-link" to={`/places/${props.id}`}>
            press to view
          </Link>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    </>
  );
}

export default oneCard;
```

i get the cardsArr data to an arr of objects and see the cardlist component props in the console, but it's not appear in the body.
i want to dispay it in the cards.

thnx for the helping!

Answer (score 1):

I use to make this mistake a lot. What you need to do is in your `cardsList` component, where you are mapping through your props, you need to explicitly return the component like this. Good luck on your React journey!

```js
        {props.cards.map((card) => {
            return(
            <OneCard
                key={card.id}
                id={card.id}
                image={card.image}
                country={card.country}
                fullName={card.fullName}
                cost={card.cost}
                duration={card.duration}
            />)
        })}
```

Comment: One alternatie would be to not put the return value in a block. e.g. `(card) => (<OneCard ... />)`

Comment: @Hikash very true! I just felt like using return was the most clear way to explain what he was missing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to return something from your `cards?.map` call. When you use a function literal with brace-syntax you explicitly need a `return` statement for example

```
{props.cards.map((card) => {
          return (<OneCard
            key={card.id}
            id={card.id}
            image={card.image}
            country={card.country}
            fullName={card.fullName}
            cost={card.cost}
            duration={card.duration}
          />
         );
})}
```

However, if your only calculating an expression (`<OneCard/>` is effectively an expression) then you can omit the `return` statement, for example

```
{props.cards.map((card) =>
          <OneCard
            key={card.id}
            id={card.id}
            image={card.image}
            country={card.country}
            fullName={card.fullName}
            cost={card.cost}
            duration={card.duration}
          />;
        )}
```

Comment: thank u ! i cant believe i forgot that 'return' haha